# How to print in colours in the shell (PYTHON)

Tags: python-3.x, colors

I am studying tech in Australia, and I am having trouble with getting this to print in colour. I would like to print the 'x's on the board in black (not blue), and so the numbers appear in blue ( in another part of the code). How do I print in black?

```
 # creates the 'x's to display on the minesweeper board
    for i in range(board_row):
        board.append(["x"] * board_row)
```

ASCII and ANSI don't work, and I can't figure out how to get the modules like Blessings and colorama in to python

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)